# Graph on $2017$ edges with chromatic number $3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Graph $G$ is simple, has chromatic number $3$ and $2017$ edges.

How can I figure out if this graph is possible or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take $C_{2017}$, the cycle on $2017$ nodes. All odd cycles have chromatic number $3$.

Answer (score 6):

Or, take a $K_3$ (forces chromatic number to be 3, has 3 edges) and then $2014$ independent edges.  This graph has $2015$ (disjoint) connected components... and it generalizes nicely in that you could easily modify it to have chromatic number 3 and any number of edges ($\geq 3$).

Comment: Or, for an easy-to-visualize connected version, a triangle with a long tail.

Answer (score 4):

You can also produce such a graph with $90$ vertices by adding one edge to  $K_{48,42}$. (Probably fewer vertices are also possible).

Comment: Omitting $11$ edges from $K_{26,26,26}$ gets you down to $78$ vertices, which I think is the fewest possible.